# CALayer animation beginTime

Tags: ios, calayer, caanimation

I'm developing a keyframe animation editor for iOS that allows the user to create simple animations and view them, plotted against a timeline. The user is able to drag the timeline in order to change the current time.

This means that I need to be able to start an animation at a user specified time.

Whilst I can achieve this behaviour, i also am experiencing an annoying glitch every time I re-add the animation to the layer. This glitch causes the first frame of the animation to flash very quickly before CoreAnimation respects the begin time. I can mitigate the effects of this ever so slightly by setting the layer.alpha to 0 before the flush, and 1 after the flush however this still results in a nasty single frame(ish) flash!

I have recreated a sample view controller that demonstrates the code required to "change the time" of the running animation but as this project is so simple, you don't really see the negative effects of the flush:
https://gist.github.com/chrisbirch/5cafca50804cf9d778ccd0fdc9e68d56

Basic idea behind the code is as follows:

Each time the user changes the current time, I restart the animation and fiddle with the CALayer timing properties like so (addStoppedAnimation:line 215):

```
ani = createGroup()

animatableLayer.speed = 0

animatableLayer.add(ani, forKey: "an animation key")
let time = CFTimeInterval(slider.value)
animatableLayer.timeOffset = 0
animatableLayer.beginTime = animatableLayer.superlayer!.convertTime(CACurrentMediaTime(), from: nil) - time

CATransaction.flush()
animatableLayer.timeOffset = time// offset
print("Time changed \(time)")
```

The glitch is caused by me having to call CATransaction.flush right before I set timeOffset. Failure to call this flush results in the begin time being ignored it would seem.

I feel like I have scoured the entire internet looking for a solution to this problem but alas Im think I'm stuck.

My question is this:

Can anyone shed any light onto why it is I need to call CATransaction.flush in order for the beginTime value that I set to take effect? Looking at apple code I didn't ever see them using flush for this purpose so perhaps I have got something obvious wrong!

Many thanks in advance

Chris

Comment: are you readding the animation each time?  why not just update the offset?

Comment: The example i provided is just a very simple demo, in my real app there are many animations and the animation may not even be running as the user can set the current time to be any time from 0 to "infinity".

Comment: why not check for the animation and update the timeOffset and if the animation is not running re add the animation? Assign each animation a unique key. Save keys in an array or dictionary?

Answer (score 1):

Using your test code from the gist I have updated it to check for an animation so that there is no need to readd it.  You could us a unique ID to track all animations and store it in a dictionary with view attributes.  I did not implement this part but that is how I would do it. Hopefully I understood your issue enough.  Also I used Xcode 9 and I am not sure of the code differences.  I changed a few logic pieces so let me know if this fixes the issue.

```
UUID().uuidString //for unique string in implementation

//from your code just slightly altered.
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  CATest


//
//  CATestViewController.swift
//  SimpleCALayerTest


import UIKit

class CATestViewController: UIViewController, CAAnimationDelegate{


    var slider : UISlider!
    var animatableLayer : CALayer!

    var animationContainerView : UIView!

    var centerY : CGFloat!
    var startTranslationX : CGFloat!
    var endTranslationX : CGFloat!

    let duration = 10.0

    ///boring nibless view setup code
    override func loadView() {
        let marginX = CGFloat(10)
        let marginY = CGFloat(10)
        let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 400, height: 400))

        view.backgroundColor = .lightGray

        slider = UISlider(frame: CGRect(x: marginX, y: 0, width: 200, height: 50))
        slider.maximumValue = Float(duration)
        slider.addTarget(self, action: #selector(sliderChanged(_:)), for: .valueChanged)

        slider.addTarget(self, action: #selector(sliderDragStart(_:)), for: .touchDown)
        slider.addTarget(self, action: #selector(sliderDragEnd(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

        //A view to house an animated sublayer
        animationContainerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: marginX, y: 50, width: 200, height: 70))



        //add a play button that will allow the animation to be played without hindrance from the slider
        let playButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: marginX, y: animationContainerView.frame.maxY + marginY, width: 200, height: 50))
        playButton.setTitle("Change Frame", for: .normal)
        playButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(playAnimation), for: .touchUpInside)
        view.addSubview(playButton)

        //add a stopped ani button that will allow the animation to be played using slider
        let addStoppedAniButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: playButton.frame.origin.x, y: playButton.frame.maxY + marginY, width: playButton.frame.width, height: playButton.frame.size.height))
        addStoppedAniButton.setTitle("Pause", for: .normal)
        addStoppedAniButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(cmPauseTapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        view.addSubview(addStoppedAniButton)



        let animatableLayerWidth = animationContainerView.bounds.width / CGFloat(4)
        centerY = animationContainerView.bounds.midY
        startTranslationX = animatableLayerWidth / CGFloat(2)
        endTranslationX = animationContainerView.bounds.width - animatableLayerWidth / CGFloat(2)


        animationContainerView.backgroundColor = .white
        animationContainerView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.5).cgColor
        animationContainerView.layer.borderWidth = 1

        view.addSubview(slider)
        view.addSubview(animationContainerView)

        //Now add a layer to animate to the container
        animatableLayer = CALayer()
        animatableLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow.cgColor
        animatableLayer.borderWidth = 1
        animatableLayer.borderColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.5).cgColor
        var r = animationContainerView.bounds.insetBy(dx: 0, dy: 4)
        r.size.width = animatableLayerWidth
        animatableLayer.frame = r
        animationContainerView.layer.addSublayer(animatableLayer)

        self.view = view
    }

    @objc func cmPauseTapped(_ sender : UIButton){
        if animatableLayer.speed == 0{
            resume()
        }else{
            pause()
        }
    }

    @objc func sliderChanged(_ sender: UISlider){
        if animatableLayer.speed == 0{
            let time = CFTimeInterval(sender.value)
            animatableLayer.speed = 0
            animatableLayer.timeOffset = time// offset
            print("Time changed \(time)")
        }
    }

    var animations = [CAAnimation]()

    func addAnimations(){
        let ani = CAAnimation()
        animations.append(ani)
    }

    @objc func sliderDragStart(_ sender: UISlider)
    {
        if animatableLayer.speed > 0{
            animatableLayer.speed = 0
        }
        addStoppedAnimation()
    }

    func pause(){
        //just updating slider
        if slider.value != Float(animatableLayer.timeOffset){
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
                self.slider.setValue(Float(self.animatableLayer.timeOffset), animated: true)
            })
        }

        animatableLayer.timeOffset = animatableLayer.convertTime(CACurrentMediaTime(), from: nil)
        animatableLayer.speed = 0

    }

    func resume(){
        if let _ = animatableLayer.animationKeys()?.contains("an animation key"){
            animatableLayer.speed = 1.0;
            let pausedTime = animatableLayer.timeOffset
            animatableLayer.beginTime = 0.0;
            let timeSincePause = animatableLayer.convertTime(CACurrentMediaTime(), from: nil) - pausedTime
            animatableLayer.beginTime = timeSincePause;
            return
        }

        print("Drag End with need to readd animation")
        ani = createGroup()
        animatableLayer.speed = 1
        animatableLayer.add(ani, forKey: "an animation key")
        let time = CFTimeInterval(slider.value)
        animatableLayer.timeOffset = time
        animatableLayer.beginTime = CACurrentMediaTime()

    }
    @objc func sliderDragEnd(_ sender: UISlider){
        resume()
    }

    //Animations

    var ani : CAAnimationGroup!

    func createGroup() -> CAAnimationGroup
    {
        let ani = CAAnimationGroup()

        ani.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
        ani.duration = 10
        ani.delegate = self

        ani.animations = [createTranslationAnimation(),createColourAnimation()]
        return ani
    }
    func createTranslationAnimation() -> CAKeyframeAnimation
    {
        let ani = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "position")
        ani.delegate = self
        ani.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
        ani.duration = 10
        ani.values = [CGPoint(x:0,y:centerY),CGPoint(x:endTranslationX,y:centerY)]
        ani.keyTimes = [0,1]
        return ani
    }

    func createColourAnimation() -> CAKeyframeAnimation
    {
        let ani = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "backgroundColor")
        ani.delegate = self
        ani.isRemovedOnCompletion = false

        ani.duration = 10
        ani.values = [UIColor.red.cgColor,UIColor.blue.cgColor]
        ani.keyTimes = [0,1]

        return ani
    }

    func animationDidStop(_ anim: CAAnimation, finished flag: Bool) {
        print("Animation Stopped")
    }

    func animationDidStart(_ anim: CAAnimation) {
        print("Animation started")
    }

    func addStoppedAnimation()
    {
        if let _ = animatableLayer.animationKeys()?.contains("an animation key"){
            slider.value += 0.5
            sliderChanged(slider)
            return
            //we do not want to readd it
        }
        ani = createGroup()
        animatableLayer.speed = 0
        animatableLayer.add(ani, forKey: "an animation key")
        let time = CFTimeInterval(slider.value)
        animatableLayer.timeOffset = time
        animatableLayer.beginTime = CACurrentMediaTime()
    }

    @objc func playAnimation(){
      addStoppedAnimation()
    }

}
```

Comment: Nice! thanks very much. Reason I didnt go down this path to begin with is because I have several use cases. Problem is, my app allows user to drag the "keyframes" of the animation around whilst they are playing thus I will have to restart these animations. Do you think your above solution could be tailored to work with restarting "changed" animations?

Comment: yep i can understand. i would assign a unique key and view in a dictionary and use map and check for the keys in the dictionary against all your animation keys to either update or readd. neat bit of code by yourself.

Comment: Yeah sure, but then I will have the same problem as the original code I would have thought?

Comment: are the animations allowed preset?

Comment: No, they are completely specified by user. The keyframe editor is part of a larger app

Comment: but does the user choose kColorAnimation or kPositionAnimation, etc. if so saves those against the view in a dictionary and check if they are present before adding.

Comment: Sorry think we have our wires crossed. My issue is not with keeping track of animations that need starting or updating. In my real app - Im storing pretty much everything to do with the animations so I know exactly whats running and what could be updated (I'm going to use your code to improve my other project by not re-adding everything all the time, which i agree is silly)

Comment: My issue now is how to restart an animation whose keyframes have been altered in someway, i.e dragged or user changed the value of a property. I.e the above code allows me to do that but it glitches all over the shop :)

Comment: i am pretty sure i had it so the code i put up could be restarted after dragging. i will check and get back with you later today

Comment: Yes the code restarts if the animation ends, the problem I have is that I need to replace an ongoing animation due to me having changed ones of the animations keyframes "mid-flight". This results in my initial problem of having to call CATrasnaction flush in order to replace the animation at the correct time